# Adding linear model abline to log-log plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I cannot seem to replicate the adding of a linear abline to a log-log ggplot.  Code below illustrates.  Grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.

```
d = data.frame(x = 100*sort(rlnorm(100)), y = 100*sort(rlnorm(100)))
(fit = lm(d$y ~ d$x))

# linear plot to check fit
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(intercept = coef(fit)[1], slope = coef(fit)[2], col='red')

# log-log base plot to replicate in ggplot (don't worry if fit line looks a bit off)
plot(d$x, d$y, log='xy')
abline(fit, col='red', untf=TRUE)

# log-log ggplot
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(intercept = coef(fit)[1], slope = coef(fit)[2], col='red') +
  scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you are plotting linear relationship between x and y, you can use `geom_smooth()` with `method="lm"`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)+
  scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
```

### UPDATE

It seems that `geom_abline()` doesn't have argument `untf=TRUE` as for function `abline()`.

Workaround would be to use `geom_line()` and new data frame in it that contains y values calculated using coefficients of your linear model or using function `predict()`.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=d$x,y=coef(fit)[1]+coef(fit)[2]*d$x))+
  scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_line(data=data.frame(x=d$x,y=predict(fit)))+
  scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: That's useful Didzis, but what if I want to draw the linear model fit line in log-log coordinates?  This is what [abline's 'untf' argument](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/abline.html) does.

Comment: @geotheory Updated my answer with workaround for this problem

Comment: Clever, and +1 for bringing to my attention the elegant predict() function :)

Comment: Nice answer and thanks. Any idea on how to get the new regression line to extend to the edges of the plot? My best guess is to extend the values of x that you use in the prediction, but then you'd have to place limits on the plot after the fact. This is a less than  ideal approach.

Comment: It seems that the way to do this is fit the regression in logs and then use `geom_abline` before transforming the scales. See below

Answer (score 6):

If you run the regression in logs, fit the line, and the transform the scales, you can use `geom_abline`

```
d = data.frame(x = 100*sort(rlnorm(100)), y = 100*sort(rlnorm(100)))
(fit = lm(log(d$y) ~ log(d$x)))

p <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
    geom_abline(intercept = coef(fit)[1], slope = coef(fit)[2], col='red') +
    scale_y_continuous(trans=log_trans()) +
    scale_x_continuous(trans=log_trans())
```

[image]

Comment: A note that `scale_*_continuous(trans="log10")+` will not work. If you want round axis tick values, consider using `scale_*_continuous(trans="log",breaks=c(...))`.