# How to calculate the slopes of different linear regression lines on multiple plots in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lm, facet

I am now using **facet** to draw multi-plots of distribution by different value of i and find the **slope** of each regression line on corresponding plot.

The format of my dataset is as follows and here is the link to the whole file (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_biBFUMCaA2SGlFc2I0OTd3djA/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

I use the following R code to draw multiple plot:

```
bound = read.csv("strength_distribution")
sp <- ggplot(bound, aes(x,y)) + geom_point(shape=1)+ 
scale_y_log10()+ scale_x_log10()+ggtitle("Node Strength Distribution")+
      theme(plot.title= element_text(size =16, face ="bold", 
              lineheight = 8, vjust=1), aspect.ratio=1)+
      stat_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE) + scale_shape_identity()
sp + facet_wrap( ~ i, ncol=3, scales = "free_x" )
ggplotly()
```

And then I get the following plot:

[image]

I find that there are multiple ways to calculate the slope of a regression line for one plot, but don't have a clue on writing a function to calculate the slopes for multiple regression lines in multiple plots. Does anyone know how to deal with this situation? Thanks.

Comment: `sapply(split(df, df$i), function(data) coef(lm(y ~ x, data))[1])` without ggplot. I looked quickly through the plot build and didnt see anything that would be useful, but to me it would be easier to do it separately

Comment: @roman yeah my mistake

Comment: @rawr: thanks for your answer, is that right I should change coef(lm(y ~ x, data))[1] to coef(lm(y ~ x, data))[2]

Comment: Yes should be [2] you're right, [1] would give you the y intercept

Comment: @rawr: one last question, because I draw my figures on a log-log plot, so if I want to calculate the slope of regression line, shall I also add log to coef, such as coef(lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data))[2] , but this returns an error

Comment: `coef(lm(log10(y) ~ log10(x), data))` should work, see the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617261/adding-linear-model-abline-to-log-log-plot-in-ggplot)

Comment: @rawr: thx, now I get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2994949/rawr) has a perfect answer for you in the comments but in case you're interested...

If you are doing reasonably complex stuff to subsets of your data then its well worth checking out the `group_by() %>% nest() %>% map()` workflow in R. I will demonstrate with a simple example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
data(iris)
```

these are some functions that you want to apply to your subsets.

```
doModel <- function(dat) lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, dat)
getSlope <- function(mod) coef(mod)[2]
```

You can apply them as follows.

```
models <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, doModel)) %>% 
  mutate(slope = map(model, getCoef))

models$slope
```

What happened is that you created some data.frame's within a data.frame with `nest()`. Then you used `map()` to apply a function to each sub data.frame. This sort of workflow can get really useful if you have quite nuanced things to do to each subset.

I highly recommend watching [hadleys talk on this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rz3_FDVt9eg). Happy to help more if you want...

Comment: thanks a lot and gain a lot. Just one extra question, now I have three datasets A, B, and C and each of them has the same format as the file listed in the question. Although these datasets have a common variable i, the number of corresponding x and y is different from each other. So if I want to draw these three datasets, such as three lines on a plot with a specific value of i, so if i is from 0 to 1 with an increment of 0.1, there should be 11plots and each plot has three lines. Is that possible?

Comment: Do you mean the number of rows is different in different subsets? ggplot with facetting will be able to handle that no problem.