# ggplot2 and log-log axis in R: How do I create correct diagonal lines? (GOF plots)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to the use of R and therefore still have difficulties. Currently I am trying to plot a twofold line with diagonal lines in a plot with logarithmic axes. Unfortunately it does not work. The diagonals meet at 1, but should actually originate near 0. With linear axes everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for the support.

Code for linear plot:

```
ggplot(data=A, aes(x=value_predicted, y=value_observed, colour=factor(ckd_stage)))+
geom_point(na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, size=1)+
theme_bw()+
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(conc_min,conc_max))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(conc_min,conc_max))+
xlab("prediction")+
ylab("observed")+
labs(colour="stages")+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 2, colour="grey", linetype="dashed")+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0.5, colour="grey", linetype="dashed")+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1.25, colour="black", linetype="dashed")+
geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0.8, colour="black", linetype="dashed")
```

Code for log-log plot:

```
ggplot(data=A, aes(x=value_predicted, y=value_observed, colour=factor(ckd_stage)))+
geom_point(na.rm=TRUE)+
geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1, size=1)+
theme_bw()+
scale_x_log10(limits=c(conc_min,conc_max))+
scale_y_log10(limits=c(conc_min,conc_max))+
xlab("prediction")+
ylab("observed")+
labs(colour="stages")+
abline(a = 0, b =2, untf=TRUE)+
abline(a = 0, b = 0.5,untf=TRUE)+
abline(a = 0, b =1.25, untf=TRUE)+
abline(a = 0, b = 0.8, untf=TRUE)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617261/adding-linear-model-abline-to-log-log-plot-in-ggplot

Comment: unfortunately I dont understand how to implement the suggestions in my code